# How to make the top datarow in gridview editable and leave the rest in readonly?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on an application that displays data in a gridview. The end-user would like to **edit only the top row**. How do I do it programatically?

Comment: This is definitely a GridView and not a DataGridView?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! Yes, it takes __four__ letters more to type, but when asking for help here is __not__ the time to be so lazy..!

Comment: The question should be tagged with `DataGridView`.

Comment: For a DataGridView you can set each cell in the row to ReadOnly true or false.

Comment: You can set the `ReadOnly` property of rows in a loop to `true`, except the first row. `this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].ReadOnly = true;`

Comment: Very useful tip. Thanks Reza Aghaei.

Comment: Or loop `dataGridView1.Rows[i].ReadOnly = i!=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call this below code after loading the grid data:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid.Rows)
   row.ReadOnly = row.Index != 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add the below code to the event CellBeginEdit of datagridview;**

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex != 0)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```